# Convert object to JSON without escapings on strings

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have searched the web for answer and everywhere is done like this:

```
        JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        params.put("Event", gson.toJson(myEvent));
```

But this is returning me Json like this with all escapings on `"`:

```
"Event":"{\"Test1\":\"TestValue1\",\"TestObj\":{\"Test2\":\"TestValue2\",\"Test3\":\"TestValue3\"...
```

How can I have Json free of all escapings, just like this:

```
"Event":"{"Test1":"testValue1","TestObj":{"Test2":"testValue2","Test3":"testValue3"...
```

Cheers mates.

Comment: there is no way you can do like that

Comment: what am I missing Jonjongot

Comment: urmm. what missing? the escape character

Comment: yes I have to rid of them somehow. But I cant figure it out

Comment: why you want to remove it?

Comment: my api that I am passing the Json is returning me error, trying to make object out of the passed Json. And it must be clean of the escapings.

Comment: you can try: `"Event':'{'Test1':'testValue1','TestObj':{'Test2':'testValue2'...".replace("'","\"");`

Comment: I don't want to raplace symbols :( it is not beautiful, it must has an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer, here it is:

I am passing property by property:

```
        createEvent.put("Test1", myObj1.Test1);
        createEvent.put("Test2", myObj2.Test2);
```

and the Notelist problem is solved like this:

```
        JSONArray mJSONArray = new JSONArray(myNoteList);

        createEvent.put("Notes", mJSONArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

I can pass the object like this, property by property:

```
        createEvent.put("Test1", myObj1.Test1);
        createEvent.put("Test2", myObj2.Test2);
```

and pass the Json to api, but Notes is with escapings:

```
        String myNoteListJson = new Gson().toJson(myNoteList);
        createEvent.put("Notes", myNoteListJson);
```